# newtype around ST causes type error

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, higher-rank-types

When I try to load the following code under GHC 7.4.1:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.ST

newtype M s a = M { unM :: ST s a }

runM :: (forall s. M s a) -> a
runM (M m) = runST m
```

It fails with the following message:

```
test.hs:9:14:
    Couldn't match type `s0' with `s'
      because type variable `s' would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      a type expected by the context: ST s a
    The following variables have types that mention s0
      m :: ST s0 a (bound at test.hs:9:9)
    In the first argument of `runST', namely `m'
    In the expression: runST m
    In an equation for `runM': runM (M m) = runST m
```

Why does this fail, when `M` is just a wrapper around `ST`?

(My actual program has a few transformers stacked on top – this is just a minimal case.)

---

**EDIT**: It seems adding a `let` fixes the issue:

```
runM m = let M m' = m in runST m
```

However, if `TypeFamilies` is enabled (as it is in my real code), it fails again.

Comment: I believe this is because

Comment: Sorry, I disproved my own hypothesis :(

Comment: But what was your hypothesis? Even if it is wrong, at least we can learn that it is a wrong hypothesis.

Comment: I suspect that pattern matching is creating a fresh type variable and turning `m` into `ST newTypeVar a`. Which actually seems plausible. At which point your error is just the normal `st` monad complaining about a rigid type var instead of the expected rank 2 type

Comment: See also this post on [MonoLocalBinds](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/LetGeneralisationInGhc7).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a problem with the pattern matches + rankntypes.

GHC infers `m` to have the type `ST ??? a` where `???` is a type variable that can unify with anything and has to unify with something*. So we then pass it along to `runST` and `runST` wants an `ST s a` so `m` unifies with it and `???` unifies with `s`. But wait, now we're unifying with `s` outside the scope where `s` is defined scope so disaster.

A simpler example is

```
test (M m) = (m :: forall t . ST t a) `seq` ()
```

And again we get the same error because we attempt to unify with the type of `m` using `t`, but `t` is in too small a scope.

The simplest solution is simply not to create this type variable with

```
 test m = runST (unM m)
```

here `unM` returns a good and true polymorphic `ST` that `runST` is happy with. You can use `let` since it's by default polymorphic but since `-XTypeFamilies` will make let monomorphic it will blow up just like pattern matching as you've discovered.

---

** It appears that `m` is monomorphic. `let` is polymorphic without type families so I suspect this is what's going on. It behaves like it

```
test :: forall a. (forall t. M t a) -> ()
test (M m) = (m :: ST Bool a) `seq` (m :: ST Int a) `seq` ()
```

Errors trying to unify `Bool` and `Int` as you would expect from a monomorphic type variable. Why does every weird type error I find seem to hide some form of monomorphic type variable..